# C# How to read .keystore file? Certificate information like Valid from, until and Owner, issuer?

Tags: c#, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore

I am having .keystore file which has all the information of certificated available on serve machine. When I am using command prompt to get the details of certificate by below command

command: Keytool -list -v -keystore filename.keystore

I am trying to build a C# utility which check subjected details of all the certificates. 
How I can implement this using C#? Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to run the same command line command with C#?

Comment: Use Process Class.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks Ryan Wilson, No, I am trying to get the result of this command. Means C# code should able to call by any method (either by executing same command or another way from C# code) so that I can get the details of certificates